# How can I automate an existing instance of Internet Explorer using Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, internet-explorer, automation, win32ole

I am struggling to get control of an IE preview control which is 'Internet Explorer_Server' class on an external windows application with perl.

Internet Explorer_Server is the class name of the window, I've found it with Spy++. and here’s my assertion code of it

```
$className = Win32::GUI::GetClassName($window); 
if ($className eq "Internet Explorer_Server") { 
    ... 
}
```

I can get a handle of that 'Internet Explorer_Server' with `Win32::GUI::GetWindow`, but have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Can you clarify what ***Internet Explorer_Server*** is?

Comment: *Internet Explorer_Server* is the class name of the window, I've found it with Spy++.

and here’s my assertion code of it

$className = Win32::GUI::GetClassName($window);
if ($className eq "Internet Explorer_Server") {
   ...
}

Comment: @crowdy I updated my answer in light of your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Updated:*** You are going down the wrong path. What you need is [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::OLE).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

my $shell = get_shell();
my $windows = $shell->Windows;

my $count = $windows->{Count};

for my $item ( 1 .. $count ) {
    my $window = $windows->Item( $item );
    my $doc = $window->{Document};
    next unless $doc;
    print $doc->{body}->innerHTML;
}

sub get_shell {
    my $shell;
    eval {
        $shell = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Shell.Application');
    };

    die "$@\n" if $@;

    return $shell if defined $shell;

    $shell = Win32::OLE->new('Shell.Application')
        or die "Cannot get Shell.Application: ",
               Win32::OLE->LastError, "\n";
}
__END__
```

So, this code finds a window with a `Document` property and prints the HTML. You will have to decide on what criteria you want to use to find the window you are interested in.

[`ShellWindows` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773970%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks, but that's not exactly what I want. I don't want to create a new instance of IE. I want the control of IE already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~abeltje/Win32-IE-Mechanize-0.009/lib/Win32/IE/Mechanize.pm). I am not sure whether you can control an **existing** IE window with this module, but accessing a single URL should be possible in about five lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Samie http://samie.sourceforge.net/ as this is a perl module to control IE

Comment: *sigh* Where do I start?

Let's ignore that comic strip character on the homepage for a second... Samie is not on CPAN. And when you want to download it, all you get is a zip file with a windows-style installer inside. It's packaged up like a proprietary software component. Speaking of which, on the homepage the license is not shown.